# NPS and RHEL ssh configuration

Tags: ssh, rhel6, nps

We have setup windows NPS and RHEL radius client using pam_radius module from freeradius.org for ssh. But on a linux client I see the error `pam_radius_auth: Got RADIUS response code 3` in `/var/log/secure`. Code 3 means `Access Rejected`, but from a windows client when I tested using a radius testing tool, the connection was successful and got code 2, code 2 means `Access granted`. In NPS log I am getting below:

```
<Event>
 <Timestamp data_type="4">07/04/2015 10:21:02.913</Timestamp>
 <Computer-Name data_type="1">MYADDomainController</Computer-Name>
 <Event-Source data_type="1">IAS</Event-Source>
 <User-Name data_type="1">MYlinuxuser</User-Name>
 <NAS-Identifier data_type="1">sshd</NAS-Identifier>
 <NAS-Port data_type="0">3360</NAS-Port>
 <NAS-Port-Type data_type="0">5</NAS-Port-Type>
 <Service-Type data_type="0">8</Service-Type>
 <Calling-Station-Id data_type="1">MYWindowsClientIP</Calling-Station-Id>
 <Client-IP-Address data_type="3">MYMyLinuxRadiusClientNameInNPSIP</Client-IP-Address>
 <Client-Vendor data_type="0">0</Client-Vendor>
 <Client-Friendly-Name data_type="1">MyLinuxRadiusClientNameInNPS</Client-Friendly-Name>
 <Proxy-Policy-Name data_type="1">Use Windows authentication for all users</Proxy-Policy-Name>
 <Provider-Type data_type="0">1</Provider-Type>
  <SAM-Account-Name data_type="1">MyDomainName\MYlinuxuser</SAM-Account-Name>
  <Fully-Qualifed-User-Name data_type="1">MyDomainName\MYlinuxuser</Fully-Qualifed-User-Name>
  <Class data_type="1">311 1 MyRadiusServer 07/04/2015 05:14:52 15</Class>
  <Authentication-Type data_type="0">1</Authentication-Type>
  <Packet-Type data_type="0">1</Packet-Type>
  <Reason-Code data_type="0">0</Reason-Code>
  </Event>
<Event>
  <Timestamp data_type="4">07/04/2015 10:21:02.913</Timestamp>
  <Computer-Name data_type="1">MYADDomainController</Computer-Name>
  <Event-Source data_type="1">IAS</Event-Source>
  <Class data_type="1">311 1 MyRadiusServer 07/04/2015 05:14:52 15</Class>
  <Authentication-Type data_type="0">1</Authentication-Type>
  <Fully-Qualifed-User-Name data_type="1">MyDomainName\MYlinuxuser</Fully-Qualifed-User-Name>
  <SAM-Account-Name data_type="1">MyDomainName\MYlinuxuser</SAM-Account-Name>
  <Provider-Type data_type="0">1</Provider-Type>
  <Proxy-Policy-Name data_type="1">Use Windows authentication for all users</Proxy-Policy-Name>
  <Client-IP-Address data_type="3">MYMyLinuxRadiusClientNameInNPSIP</Client-IP-Address>
  <Client-Vendor data_type="0">0</Client-Vendor>
  <Client-Friendly-Name data_type="1">MyLinuxRadiusClientNameInNPS</Client-Friendly-Name>
  <Packet-Type data_type="0">3</Packet-Type>
  <Reason-Code data_type="0">16</Reason-Code>
</Event>
```

In the Windows event viewer under NPS I dont see any errors. What I am missing in the NPS?

Answer (score 1):

The [reason code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197570(v=ws.10).aspx) given in your event log is 16, which is [unambiguous](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197464(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Authentication failed due to a user credentials mismatch. Either the user name provided does not match an existing user account or the password was incorrect.